# Preparing Saturated Carbon Dioxide

Tags: experimental-chemistry, solubility

I'm doing a chemistry lab where I'm collecting data to create a solubility curve for carbon dioxide at different temperatures. I'm using carbonated water and my concern is that, by heating or cooling the solution, will it be saturated with carbon dioxide after exposing it to the air for a small period of time? I'm guessing that this will not be the case.

I know I can add carbon dioxide to water samples by exhaling into them but, is there a way to determine that it has been saturated without using a pre-existing solubility curve?